# Azure Open AI API: why do I get "message": "'str' object has no attribute 'append'"

Tags: azure, openai-api

Post: https://cefyrai.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/***/extensions/chat/completions?api-version=2023-08-01-preview

```html
{
  "temperature": 0,
  "top_p": 1,
  "frequency_penalty": 0,
  "presence_penalty": 0,
  "max_tokens": 1500,
  "stop": "null",

 "dataSources": [
        {
            "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch",
            "parameters": {
                "endpoint": "https://cefyrcognitivesearch.search.windows.net",
                "key": "ldbRsnEtdrrds1FO********",
                "indexName": "dataverseindex2"
         
            }
        }
    ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "Fortell en vits"
    }
  ]
}
```

Gives me this:

```html
{
    "error": {
        "requestid": "984ebc76-9013-4ec3-8f01-084d7e6d649e",
        "code": 500,
        **"message": "'str' object has no attribute 'append'"**
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information, I have reproduced the issue.
[image]

It seems there is an issue with `"stop": "null"` parameter in payload, to fix the issue you can remove the parameter

This should not make any difference to the output as the `default value` of the parameter is also `null.`

Once the parameter removed from payload, the request executed successfully.
[image]

For more details regarding parameters, you can check this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference)